# self._wrapped = settings(settings_module) TypeError: 'LazySettings' object is not callable

Tags: django

Error is :  self._wrapped = settings(settings_module)
            TypeError: 'LazySettings' object is not callable

django/conf/**init**.py

self._wrapped = settings(settings_module)
 self._configure_logging()

Note : i am getting error over here

Error: File "D:\Forms_django\BJP\manage.py", line 10, in 
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

manage.py

**execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)**

Getting error in this line.Before its working fine.
but when i added Project which is created in 1.4 version I got this error

Please help me out with detailed solution because i am quite new to the django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its Settings class not the settings variable

```
from django.conf import Settings
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
```

settings variable : A lazy proxy for either global Django settings or a custom settings object.The user can manually configure settings prior to using them. Otherwise,
Django uses the settings module pointed to by DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Actually i made some editing in the Deefault file. conf/__init__.py. Thank you.